# Getting an array index (0,1,2,..8) from bit masking value (1,2,4,8..256) without using log2(n). Maybe a design issue

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators

I'm working on a component where I put in data and I get different data as a result. The input is always the same (3 Objects). 
From these 3 Objects up to 9 other Objects can be calculated. One calculation for each output Object is performed.
Before the output data is calculated I want to set which of the 9 Objects shall be calculated.

1. Set input data
2. Set which output data shall be calculated
3. Get Output data

I'm working in Visual C++ (C99). At the moment I'm facing a bit of a design problem here. 
After I set the input data, I am using a bit mask to configure which output data is supposed to be calculated.

```
const int  foo1 = 1;   //000000001
const int  foo2 = 2;   //000000010
const int  foo3 = 4;   //000000100
const int  foo4 = 8;   //000001000
const int  foo5 = 16;  //000010000
const int  foo6 = 32;  //000100000
const int  foo7 = 64;  //001000000
const int  foo8 = 128; //010000000
const int  foo9 = 256; //100000000

SetOutput(foo2 | foo4 | foo5 );
```

The data is held in an array `ARRAY[9]` . For those that have been set (foo2, foo4 and foo5) the elements contain valid data after the calculation (`ARRAY[2]`, `ARRAY[4]`, `ARRAY[5]`)

I then want to get the the resulting data.

```
GetData(foo2);
GetData(foo4);
GetData(foo5);
```

My problem is how do I get the element index from the mask values  `foo2 = 2`, `foo4 = 8` or for example `foo5 = 16`?
The only possibility would be taking `log2(n)` and get `2`, `3` and `4`, which would be the correct element indexes of `ARRAY`.

Is there a simpler way than this?
I thought about using a map instead, with the mask value (1,2,4,8...256) as key field and the calculated data in the value field.
But would prefer to keep the static array.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `log2(n)` is about as simple as it gets.

Comment: @RobertHarvey with the map it is [possible in O(1)](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/250785/31260) isn't it? 1 -> 0, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 8 -> 3 etc etc

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! wanted to avoid the expensive double to int hassle tho...

Comment: Why do you need to go from bitmask bits to indices?  Can you write the critical parts directly in terms of the indices, and apply a MASKIFY() operator to obtain individual bitmask bits when you need them?  (Note: MASKIFY(n) is just (1 << (n)).)

Comment: @gnat: How is a math calculation not O(1)?

Comment: @tzippy: That expense is almost certainly inconsequential, unless you're doing some sort of high-speed real-time lookup on equipment requiring nanosecond precision.  Measure it and see.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there's no math, only map lookup: `map.get(fooN)` will give index corresponding to fooN, ie log(fooN)

Comment: @gnat: But `log2(n)` is math, and so is a hash calculation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey log2 is precalculated and is within map already. Lookup is O(1) [as explained here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/250785/31260) isn't it

Comment: @gnat: I think we're saying the same thing.  The difference is that `log2(n)` doesn't require another data structure at all.  Think of it as a perfect hash calculation with no possible collisions.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm I wanted to use bit masks so that I would only need one call `SetOutput` with one parameter. This parameter being the ORed bit masks.

Comment: Understand that O(1) is not necessarily equal to O(1).  O(1) means time K1 * 1, while O(n) means time K2 * n.  If K1 = 1,000,000 and K2 = 42, then O(1) is NOT preferable to O(n) for n < 25000.  A traditional log2(x) requires quite a few floating-point operations, which tend to be expensive.

Comment: [Fast function to compute log2 for 64 bit integers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11398748/102937)

Comment: The approach seems backwards.  The constants should be set to the offsets into the array.  The bitmask can be manipulated by left shifting 1 by the constant. edit: Now that I see the rest of the posts I see that  John R. Strohm and I agree.

Answer (score 2):

An array with 257 entries will be fast, portable, and again fast. Many compilers provide a very fast built-in function to count leading or trailing zero bits in a number, for example __builtin_clz in gcc and Clang, which is likely about hundred times faster than a call to the log2 function.

Comment: Good answer about using the array (+1),  Would the anonymous downvoter care to state their case?